# Regex expression for empty string that accept number with 1 place decimal?

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression for empty string that accept number with 1
 place decimal

Accepted value

```
[blank space]
1.1
2.1
3.1
22
12
0
empty string
```

Not accepted

```
q.q
1q
.0
.00
```

Tried

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,1})?$
```

**but it's no idea for blank space**

Comment: Do you mean that number *or* a space? Try [`^( |[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/VHRQiP/2)

Comment: What do you need to do? Please clarify the question.

Comment: that it should also accept Empty string

Comment: But https://regex101.com/r/VHRQiP/2 (the link from the top comment) shows it accepts an empty string. How are you using the regex? Please show the code.

Comment: I believe the current issue is not regex related. You must be using it in some environment that filters the input before it comes to the regex engine or some other conditions are in use. E.g. "required" attribute in the HTML input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?: |[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)?$
```

You can use an alternation to either match an single space, or to match your number pattern for a whole number or a number with at most one digit past the decimal place.  Note that empty string is also a valid input, because the entire pattern has the form `^(...)?$`, which allows for no input.  I removed `{1,1}`, since `[0-9]` implicitly means only one number.

## Demo

Comment: @DeepakJain By "blank space" do you mean nothing, or a single space?  For no input, I think you should handle that in your app layer.

Comment: @L3viathan I had no idea of this, thanks for the edit :-)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
^( |[0-9]+(\.[0-9])?)?$
```